# Bootstrap 4 how to push 2nd col to next row when 1st col has a lot of text

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm pretty close, but the only problem is that the long text in the first col does not wrap.  It overflows it's parent "row".

https://www.bootply.com/qMLny5rRIW#

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-auto bg-success">Lots of text - asdfd adf adf  adf akljl;kj  adffdaasd kj; jad adsfasdf adsf;kj  asdfasdf a sdf adf asdf adf kl;j ;lk j jk;;j ;kl j j;k ;lj ; jklj ;jk ;j ;j  ;jk ;j k;k  ; ;kjasdfasdfj;k asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdfasdfasdf</div>
    <div class="col bg-warning text-right">pushed to other line</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto bg-success">small amount of text</div>
    <div class="col bg-warning text-right">same line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the bootply example, the first row with minimal text looks perfect. Col 2 stays in the same row, next to col 1.   The second row, is very close but this is my issue.  Col 2 goes down to the next row, which is what I want, but col 1 does not wrap and overflows it's row. How do I get the text in col 1 to wrap?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bcwbo3vq/

Comment: @RickSibley - that won't work for both scenarios.. it just makes the cols stack which breaks the Bootstrap grid because `cols` are no longer directly in the `.row`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the Flexbox [Grow & shrink utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) that were added in Bootstrap 4.1. Use `flex-shrink-1` which will tell the `col-auto` to "shrink" as needed, but not overflow the parent .row:

https://www.bootply.com/TFE5hRTYcD

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 bg-success">Lots of text - asdfd adf adf  adf akljl;kj  adffdaasd kj; jad adsfasdf adsf;kj ...</div>
    <div class="col bg-warning text-right">pushed to other line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/FX7UpUOwCj)

Comment: For version 4.0.0 you could use the class mw-100, which gives 100% max width [https://www.bootply.com/NB0rjg0RkA](https://www.bootply.com/NB0rjg0RkA)

[Sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/)

Comment: Thanks ZimSystem - that worked perfectly.  I had to upgrade Bootstrap from 4.0 to 4.1, but I needed to do that anyways.